# firebase rules: get all ids of collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to validate new data through firebase rules before creation.

I want to check if all strings in a field "connections" in a new document in the collection "users" are ids of documents in the collection "connections".

My approach would be to check if all strings in users.connections are included in the ids of the collection connections. With a hypothetical *getIds* it would be:

```
match/users/{id} {
   allow write: if getIds(/databases/$(database)/documents/connections).hasAll(request.resource.data.connections)
}
```

However, I don't know whether such a function exists or how i would get a list of all ids in a collection. I could also use a different approach if someone has a better idea.

Thankfull for every help :)

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do isn't possible in security rules.  Rule don't provide a way to perform a query.  You can `get()` a single document, but that's all.  Rules also don't provide a way to iterate an array, so you won't be able to write a loop to check each ID individually.  And if even if you **could** write a loop, you would be limited to 10 document `get()` per rule evaluation, so it wouldn't work for large arrays.

It sounds like you're going to need an alternative way to check this list.  The only solution that would work here is if the list was not an array, but instead a subcollection of documents.  Then you could write a rule for each document that checks to make sure that some other document exists.

Comment: Thanks :) I think saving the connections as subcollections in each users document would be problematic, as the connections contain a lot of fields and a connection is associated with many users. saving the same connection in a subcollection for each user would probably take to much space. I might create a single document storing the ids of each connection, and than use that for comparison.